# Can I estimate a VAR with different number of observations for different variables?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, stata, vector-autoregression

```
summarize    Dlprod lrea Dlop Dlrgdp inf Dlexc


Variable Obs    Mean         Std. Dev.  Min            Max

Dlprod   147    .0018841    .0175106    -.0700464   .0607834
lrea     148     1.776182   56.33475    -148.4823   183.7034
Dlop     147    .0021857    .150569     -.7221127   .4835284
Dlrgdp   147    .0060002    .0425096    -.065093    .0976105
inf      148    3.866417    3.245179    -1.426824   14.73812
Dlexc    147    .0035831    .0476469    -.085768    .2356044
```

Hi guys, I'm a little confused with the estimation of the var model. Basically, I did the ADF, DF-GLS and Phillips-Perron tests to check for stationarity of the variables and found only two variables in my var model to be stationary (i.e.  lrea - log of real economic activity index & inf - inflation rate (%))

The rest of the variables are first differenced in order to induce stationarity. However, in doing so, expectedly, I have different number of observations for my my differenced variables and the ones that are non-differenced. Can I still proceed with my estimation or is there anything else I should do? Thank you.

Comment: Cut the appropriate end of the variables, i.e. cut the oldest observation for the longer variables. Otherwise the standard estimation routines based on OLS will not work. (If you cut the newest instead, you will have a mismatch in the time index across variables; that is why you cut the oldest.)